# What's the fastest way to turn json results from an API into a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, python-requests

Below is an example of sports betting app I'm working on.

games.json()['data'] - contains the game id for each sport event for that day. The API then returns the odds for that specific game.

What's the fastest option to take json and turn it into a panda dataframe? currently looking into msgspec.

Some games can have over 5K total bets

```
master_df = pd.DataFrame()  

for game in games.json()['data']:
            
    odds_params = {'key': api_key, 'game_id': game['id'], 'sportsbook': sportsbooks}
    odds = requests.get(api_url, params=odds_params)
    for o in odds.json()['data'][0]['odds']:
        temp = pd.DataFrame()
        temp['id'] = [game['id']]
        for k,v in game.items():
            if k != 'id' and k != 'is_live':
                temp[k] = v
                
        for k, v in o.items():
            if k == 'id':
                temp['odds_id'] = v
            else:
                temp[k] = v
                
        if len(master_df) == 0:
            master_df = temp
        else:
            master_df = pd.concat([master_df, temp])
```

odds.json response snippet -

```
{'data': [{'id': '35142-30886-2023-02-08',
   'sport': 'basketball',
   'league': 'NBA',
   'start_date': '2023-02-08T19:10:00-05:00',
   'home_team': 'Washington Wizards',
   'away_team': 'Charlotte Hornets',
   'is_live': False,
   'tournament': None,
   'status': 'unplayed',
   'odds': [{'id': '4BB426518ECF',
     'sports_book_name': 'Betfred',
     'name': 'Charlotte Hornets',
     'price': 135.0,
     'checked_date': '2023-02-08T11:46:12-05:00',
     'bet_points': None,
     'is_main': True,
     'is_live': False,
     'market_name': '1st Half Moneyline',
     'home_rotation_number': None,
     'away_rotation_number': None,
     'deep_link_url': None,
     'player_id': None},  
     ....
```

By the end of this process, I usually have about 30K records in the dataframe

Comment: [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) but thats about all the help I can give without seeing some actual sample json data.

Comment: My gut tells me that time to construct the frame is insignificant compared to your ping and throughput. Do you feel that `pandas.json_normalize()` and `pandas.concat()` are the actual bottleneck? Are you attempting to time arbitrage a professional bookie with python? If this type of arbitrage was possible, I have to imagine that someone would camp on the backbone and use `c` if not assembly.

Comment: @It_is_Chris sample json has been added

Comment: JSON is a completely arbitrarily structured format. There is no single "fastest way". You haven't provided any details about the actual input you are working with (JSON is actually totally irrelevant here, since `requests` handles the deserialization, and you actually have some sort of `dict` you are working with). The code you provided uses a bunch of anti-patterns (e.g. `pd.concat` in a loop). There is probably a relatively clean way of doing what you want to do efficiently. But you need to provided us actual details

Comment: but basically, you would substantially improve your code if you didn't create single-row dataframes, concatenating them in a loop. That is creating quadratic time. behavior, with relatively high constant factors to boot. Instead, *append dicts to a list* then at the end of your loop use `pd.Dataframe(list_of_dicts)` to create your dataframe.

Comment: @bbennett36 can you add it as text to the question and not an image?

Comment: @bbennett36 are you looking for something like `pd.json_normalize(odds.json()['data'], 'odds')`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah appending dicts to a list then creating a dataframe from that list is significantly faster. I still have to add some keys to the dicts before appending but its wayyyyy faster.

Comment: yeah, it's quadratic time behavior vs linear time behavior. Like I said, it's a classic anti-pattern. dataframes do not change size efficiently likes lists. This is what lists are good at doing.

Comment: or something like `pd.json_normalize(odds.json()['data'], "odds", ['id', 'sport', 'league', 'start_date', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'is_live','tournament', 'status'],meta_prefix='data_')`

Comment: @It_is_Chris pd.json_normalize() mostly worked too. Only issue is I need from fields from  the "game" variable in the loop which throws a wrench in the normalize method. Still super helpful though for future reference thanks!

Comment: @bbennett36 no problem. You can always look at normalizing that json object as well and merge the frames together on some key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do.

```
def _create_record_(game: dict, odds: dict) -> dict:
    """
    Warning: THIS MUTATES THE INPUT
    """
    odds['id'] = "odds_id"
    # the pipe | operator is only available in dicts in recent versions of python
    # use dict(**game, **odds) if you get a TypeError
    result = game | odds
    result.pop("is_live")
    return result

def _get_odds(game: dict) -> list:
    params = {'key': api_key, 'game_id': game['id'], 'sportsbook': sportsbooks}
    return requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()['data'][0]['odds']

df = pd.DataFrame(
     [
         _create_record_(game, odds) 
         for game in games.json()['data']
         for odds in _get_odds(game)
    ]
)
```

The fact that it is in this list comprehenesion isn't relevant. And equivalent for-loop would work just as well, the point is you create a list of dicts first, then create your dataframe. This avoids the quadratic time behavior of incrementally creating a dataframe using `pd.concat`.

Comment: This solution is faster and cleaner than mine. Thanks!